# Making my own Microsoft Surface control WPF - possible?

Tags: c#, wpf, pixelsense

For a few reasons - I need to design my own control for WPF. It should be very similar to a schedule view control were appointments can be dragged and dropped onto it. It needs to be made from the controls available to me from the microsoft surface sdk. Is this a mammoth task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this.  Derive from SurfaceUserControl and everything else is the same.  Feel free to post more specific questions on this site if you get hung up on anything.

Comment: Hi Robert, well at the moment I'm really stuck on something - I'm dragging an item from a surfacelistbox and dropping it on something else. Where would I access the specifics of where the item was dropped? (i.e. if I were to drop it on a grid, what column/row it would be dropped). (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520939/small-drag-drop-prob-probably-really-simple). Thanks again.

Comment: P.S. - SurfaceDragDropEventArgs doesn't really give me much to work with (understandably only provides the name of the target control).