# Small drag drop prob (probably really simple)

Tags: c#, wpf, pixelsense

I'm dragging an item from a surfacelistbox over something else, let's say for example it's a normal wpf grid - how can I tell where (i.e. what column/row) the item has been dropped on?

Thanks a lot,

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a Panel inside each cell of your Grid.  The drop target will then be one of those panels

Comment: Brilliant Robert!! Thanks so much! Been looking for an answer to this for ages. Can't tell you how valuable that bit of info might be. Would you say this is an efficient way of implementing a schedule sort of feature? Basically need a schedule/calender-type control on the right and a list of 'jobs' on the left to drag and drop over.

Comment: Not the most efficient way... it's quick and easy but better would be to look at the Center property of the drag cursor and calculate which cell that corresponds to (without having created unused panels within each cell).

Comment: It's going to depend on where the data is coming from and when.  Post a separate (non-Surface) question asking that with more details

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help there Robert, nearly cracked this now. Here's the separate question, just in case you can further shed any light:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521563/need-a-grid-of-stackpanels-to-be-used-as-a-calendar