# Need a "grid" of stackpanels to be used as a calendar

Tags: c#, wpf, stackpanel

Ultimately, my aim is to have a grid (by grid I mean rows and columns, however it's achieved) of small stack panels to represent time intervals throughout a day. Not too disimilar from the following I suppose (simple calendar-type layout on the right):

[image]
<sub>(source: [msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/outlook/WindowsLiveWriter/ScheduleViewinOutlook2010_F3B0/clip_image002%5B4%5D_thumb.jpg))</sub>

I need a way of creating this grid dynamically and naming the panels appropriately for whenever an event is fired (to be specific - a drop event, each panel's drop event will be wired to the same method in which I must distinguish what panel (i.e. at what point in the day, and on what row) the item was dropped on).

Thanks a LOT for any help!

Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably won't get the full code to do that from here, but I can point you in the right direction.

You are probably going to want to use nested [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx). I have done something like this in the past where my outer `ItemsControl` for the Calendar was a `Grid`, and grid cell contained an inner `ItemsControl` with a `StackPanel` of `TaskItems`.

The most important part is getting your data layer right. I used `CalendarDayModel` classes, which had a `Date` property and an `ObservableCollection<TaskModel>` list. It also had Commands to handle user events, such as double-click events.

My outer `ItemsControl` was bound to the `ObservableCollection<CalendarDayModel>` and the inner `ItemsControl` were bound to the `ObservableCollection<TaskModel>`

I have some examples of an ItemsControl [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/), but take note of the last example that uses a Grid.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rachel, that's brilliant - really appreciate the feedback.  I understand how I model the data and store the lists is probably one of the trickiest parts but I'll just simply take the approach you did. My concern at the moment though is how I'm actually going to differentiate between cells/times of day with regards to which day/stackpanel called the drop event handler. I'd have to somehow name the stackpanels dynamically wouldn't I!? Please excuse the questions I have - quite new to WPF, well - very new, and I've got my hands full with this project.

Comment: @DanielMcNulty It depends on how you have your data structures. You could have the command that handles dropped items handled on the cell's DataItem, so dropping an item would execute a specific cell's event and pass it the dragged item as a parameter.